# Visualforce Email logo link is broken when received

Tags: visualforce

Please can anyone help, I have a VF email (can't use HTML as we need the VF functionality), but I can't get the header logo to work.

I have uploaded a logo into a document and ticked 'Externally Available Image'. I have used two different lines of code and neither work, although both show the image ok in the preview pane, just not when emailed. I've opened them on my laptop (Outlook) and my tablet (Chrome).

```
<img src="https://OurCompany.file.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015Q50000013wtJ"

     height="90" width="300"/>
```

And

```
 <apex:image id="Email_Header"
value="https://OurCompany.file.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015Q50000013wtJ" 
height="90" width="300"/>
```

I don't know code well, so have no idea what I need to do to make this work. It has worked in the past, I am reusing an old template (with a new image link) that I know worked once upon a time!

Any help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 3):

This is what we use in our VF email templates

```
<img src="https://mydomain.file.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015Q50000013wtJ
                                                           &oid=yourOrgId>
```

Note the `oid=` parameter for the orgId

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this but I'm still getting the same issue:

"<img src="https://OurCompany.file.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015Q50000013wtJ&oid=OurOrgID>""